# отображение значений на координатной оси в AreaChart

Tags: java, javafx

создаю приложение, которое рисует график, а именно AreaChart по координатам из файла, по оси y идут NumberAxes, по x CategoryAxes. В результате построения графика вижу, что он начинается не с начала оси координат, а оставляет место, как в начале, так и в конце. Есть ли какой-то способ исправить это? Заранее спасибо за ответ[image: areachart]

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант задать смещение в твоих формулах

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]